# Logitech wireless keyboard won't type anything -- reloaded

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, logitech-keyboard, logitech-unifying-receiver

I seem to have a similar problem to the one [scferg5](https://superuser.com/users/351695/scferg5) posted [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1000899/logitech-wireless-keyboard-wont-type-anything).

I have a Logitech K830 wireless keyboard and touchpad combo that worked fine when connected through the Logitech Unifying USB receiver until some time around Jan 2019.

After a Windows update the typing part (i.e. including Windows key, escape, arrow keys etc., but not function keys like mute, suspend etc.) of the device suddenly stopped working, while the touchpad and the aforementioned function keys still worked fine.

The device still works via Unifying receiver on a Linux OS on the same machine; *it also still works on Windows when connected via bluetooth*.

I have done everything that was suggested in [scferg5s](https://superuser.com/users/351695/scferg5) [post](https://superuser.com/questions/1000899/logitech-wireless-keyboard-wont-type-anything), i.e. toggled ease of access filter keys and rebooted and re-installed the Logitech software; furthermore I have used a different receiver with the same result and tried to install the Windows stand alone update [KB4090913](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4090913) which was referenced on the Logitech support site [here](https://support.logitech.com/en_hk/article/Issue-with-USB-devices-after-Windows-10-update-KB4074588), which Windows did not allow me to install ("not applicable to my Windows" or sth).

What could it be?

Comment: Try in the Device Manager, to expand category "Keyboards", right-click on the Logitech keyboard device and select *Uninstall* on the context menu, then reboot
for Windows 10 to install its own driver.

Comment: @harrymc: I've removed all keyboards, HIDs and mice, rebooted, cleaned registry, rebooted again, then plugged the Unifying receiver in and let windows do its driver thing: same problem.

Comment: @somebadhat: I doubt it. The setup works on the same machine with all the same components but with a Linux OS. That would point to Windows being the culprit, or Windows and Logitech not playing nice together, wouldn't it?

Comment: The only advice I have left is to get in touch with [Logitech Support](https://support.logitech.com/en_us/home).

Comment: when you are running Linux what driver is running the keyboard?

Comment: @somebadhat: Nothing proprietary or special; just the regular out-of-the-box USB driver.

Comment: I have no more ideas.

Comment: that would point to Windows as being the culprit

Answer (score 1):

I've ordered and plugged in a new Unifying receiver and got an error message upon Windows auto-install that there was a driver issue. I manually selected the driver, following [@harrymc's](https://superuser.com/users/8672/harrymc) advice not using the Logitech provided driver but rather the Windows default one, et voilà! it is working.

Thanks for your help, guys!