# Why have some keys on my Logitech k830 wireless keyboard stopped working?

Tags: wireless-keyboard, logitech-keyboard, logitech-unifying-receiver

I have a similar issue to [Logitech wireless keyboard won't type anything -- reloaded](https://superuser.com/questions/1420534/logitech-wireless-keyboard-wont-type-anything-reloaded), but in my case the issue is not isolated to Windows or the USB receiver, and it only happens with the '7', 'r', 'i', '[', ';', 'f', 'a', 'Caps Lock', 'z', '.' and 'Spacebar' keys.

I first noticed the problem on my MacBook Pro about a year ago and have since confirmed that it happens on my Windows 10 laptop too. I have tried:

- Connecting via both the Logitech Unifying Receiver and Bluetooth, with the keyboard **right next to**
  one laptop after the other and a USB charger plugged into it - makes no difference.
- Uninstalling the Logitech Unifying software completely, restarting and allowing the OS to install a generic driver (on both laptops) - no change.
- Reinstalling the above software - it won't pair with the device (never did), but it shows up in the 'Advanced' section (on both laptops).
- Turning on/off 'Filter Keys' in Windows - no change.
- Disassembling the keyboard and inspecting the circuit board and ribbon cable for damage - didn't notice anything obvious, but my eyes or inexperience with diagnosing hardware issues at this level may have deceived me.

The keyboard is quite old - I'm not sure exactly when I bought it but definitely beyond the 1 year warranty period - however I've hardly used it and have always been careful with it. This means no drops from a great height, no spilled liquids and nothing else that would obviously cause such an issue IME. **I have dropped it from small heights** quite a few times, but only on to soft surfaces, never concrete or anything like that.

**Is there anything less-obvious that I'm missing?**

Comment: If only some keys don't work and it's reproducible on different computers, then it's faulty hardware.

Comment: That was my immediate assumption as well. But I'm having trouble proving it to the store I bought it from, or Logitech themselves. I have misplaced the receipt and without proof of purchase, it seems I don't have a leg to stand on. Any suggestions for how I might fix this myself?

Comment: You could carefully clean all the parts with isopropyl alcohol. That could help remove some corrosion that's causing the issue. Other than that, electronics inside a keyboard aren't really repairable on component level.

Comment: OK thanks mate, I appreciate your time and suggestion :-) I'll give that a go, and may even try looking for a PC repair shop that's willing to look at it if need be. Doubt I'll find one though.

Comment: If cleaning doesn't work, then if it can be repaired, the repair would probably cost more than a new keyboard anyway, especially with a keyboard more than three years old.

Comment: @Gwyn Yeah good point...I wouldn't have even bothered posting about this if the damned thing hadn't cost me ~$AUD150! But I guess I may just have to bite the bullet and get a newer, hopefully better model from **any company** besides Logitech.