# Logitech keyboards pair but won't type (only volume buttons work)

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, logitech-keyboard

**Issue:**

1. I have a Logitech K830 Bluetooth keyboard. It pairs to my PC, but only the volume buttons work.
2. I thought the K830 might be broken, so I purchased a second keyboard this week, an MK360. Again, only the volume buttons work (but the mouse it comes with works perfectly).

**What I've tried:**

1. I contacted Logitech's phone support and email support. Phone support was unhelpful, and email support is still chatting with me (they take over 24hrs to respond, then I have to constantly repeat my previous emails because they forget/don't re-read them).
2. Support had me re-install keyboard drivers (through Logitech Options and a Firmware updater, which is supposed to detect which Logitech keyboard I am using but never detects either of my keyboards so this is useless).
3. Support had me try it on a different PC. I tried it on another Windows desktop (along with my own Windows desktop) and an older Windows laptop, where the issue is still appearing.
4. I have looked at other forum posts with similar issues, such as [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/1000899/logitech-wireless-keyboard-wont-type-anything) where my problem was not solved.
5. I have uninstalled my Bluetooth drivers and keyboard drivers through Device Manager, and then restarted my PC to get them to re-install. This does not solve my issue.

**Additional Resources:**

- View my YouTube video to see the problem in action here: https://youtu.be/Oezjat62uWs

Comment: Try the solutions in this pretty recent [post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware-winpc/bluetooth-keyboard-paired-but-does-not-work/df150509-4cca-4c3b-b121-036ccf07d98b?page=1).

Comment: @harrymc To Dave's solution in that link, I am seeing what a lot of the last comments are seeing, "services" tab is blank. I also tried the other comments (change Startup type to Automatic, change Log On to Local System account, etc.) and restarted my PC. No change.